# Find common values between two array of objects and store as array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have two array of objects

```
    const oldArr = [
      {
        assetDetail_ID: 1,
        asset_Condition: "",
        asset_Condition_ID: 0,
        supplier_ID: 5,
      },
      {
        assetDetail_ID: 2,
        asset_Condition: "Good",
        asset_Condition_ID: 3,
        supplier_ID: 10,
      },
    ];

    const newArr = [
      {
        assetDetail_ID: 1,
        supplier_ID: 40,
      },
      {
        assetDetail_ID: 2,
        supplier_ID: 30,
      },
    ];
```

I am trying find common values by checking with object `key` and if they are the same, get key and value pair into a new array so my final result will be

```
   expectedResult = [
      {
        assetDetail_ID: 1,
        supplier_ID: 5,
      },
      {
        assetDetail_ID: 2,
        supplier_ID: 10,
      },
    ];
```

I have tried this but I am only getting values as `[1, 5, 2, 10]`and not objects , what am I doing wrong here ?

```js
const oldArr = [{
    assetDetail_ID: 1,
    asset_Condition: "",
    asset_Condition_ID: 0,
    supplier_ID: 5,
  },
  {
    assetDetail_ID: 2,
    asset_Condition: "Good",
    asset_Condition_ID: 3,
    supplier_ID: 10,
  },
];

const newArr = [{
    assetDetail_ID: 1,
    supplier_ID: 40,
  },
  {
    assetDetail_ID: 2,
    supplier_ID: 30,
  },
];
const arr = []
oldArr.forEach((one, x) => {
  for (let i in one) {
    for (let j in newArr[x])
      if (i === j) {
        arr.push(one[i]); // If I change to arr.push(one);, it adds the whole object 
      }
  }
});

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Don't use for..in when you iterate arrays. Use forEach or map or reduce

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to do it your way,

```js
const oldArr = [{
    assetDetail_ID: 1,
    asset_Condition: "",
    asset_Condition_ID: 0,
    supplier_ID: 5,
  },
  {
    assetDetail_ID: 2,
    asset_Condition: "Good",
    asset_Condition_ID: 3,
    supplier_ID: 10,
  },
];

const newArr = [{
    assetDetail_ID: 1,
    supplier_ID: 40,
  },
  {
    assetDetail_ID: 2,
    supplier_ID: 30,
  },
];

const arr = oldArr.map((one, index) => {
  const existingKeys = Object.keys(newArr[index]).filter(key => one.hasOwnProperty(key));
  let newObj = existingKeys.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      acc[curr] = one[curr];
      return acc;
  }, {});
  return newObj;
});

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, one thing is I don't always have assetDetail_ID and supplier_ID in `newArr`, sometimes it can have more values like `asset_Condition` or `asset_Condition_ID` or even other values since the code I post here are not the full object. Is there a way to avoid writing this  `arr.push({assetDetail_ID: one.assetDetail_ID, supplier_ID: one.supplier_ID});` and instead to auto add objects which are found the same ?

Comment: In that case I think you expected result is wrong according to the newArr and oldArr. If you want only the matching keyValue pair then how come the supplier_ID: 5 is there?

Comment: I think my logic is wrong abit, thanks for that.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed

Answer (score 1):

You could take a single loop approach for both arrays and collect all `assetDetail_ID` of `newArr` in an object and get a flat array from `oldArr` by returning either a new object or an empty array.

```js
const
    oldArr = [{ assetDetail_ID: 1, asset_Condition: "", asset_Condition_ID: 0, supplier_ID: 5 }, { assetDetail_ID: 2, asset_Condition: "Good", asset_Condition_ID: 3, supplier_ID: 10 }],
    newArr = [{ assetDetail_ID: 1, supplier_ID: 40 }, { assetDetail_ID: 2, supplier_ID: 30 }],
    temp = Object.fromEntries(newArr.map(({ assetDetail_ID }) => [assetDetail_ID, true])),
    result = oldArr.flatMap(({ assetDetail_ID, supplier_ID }) => temp[assetDetail_ID]
        ? { assetDetail_ID, supplier_ID }
        : []
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function doTheJob(oldArr, newArr){
let result = new Set();
for(let i = 0; i < oldArr.length; i++){
 for(let j = 0; j < newArr.length; j++){
     if(oldArr[i].assertDetail_ID === newArr[j].assertDetail_ID){
         result.add(newArr[j]);
     }
 }
}
return Array.from(result);
}
```

This can solve your problem!

Answer (score 0):

What you need is classic JavaScript array function `filter()`

Here's an example -

```
//your array

const oldArr = [
      {
        assetDetail_ID: 1,
        asset_Condition: "",
        asset_Condition_ID: 0,
        supplier_ID: 5,
      },
      {
        assetDetail_ID: 2,
        asset_Condition: "Good",
        asset_Condition_ID: 3,
        supplier_ID: 10,
      },
    ];
```

The function -

```
function getArr(id){
    const newArr = oldArr.filter(obj => { return obj.assetDetail_ID === id})
    console.log(newArr);  //let id = 1; this will give you a sub-array where assetDetail_ID = 1
    return newArr;
}
```